# display date of week

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need the ability to display the upcoming Friday of each week within Wordpress.  We had this working on non-Wordpress in the past using the code below but that was long ago and does not work.

Example:  This week it will say, "Offer expires Friday, March 7".  Then on Saturday, it will automatically update to, "Offer expires Friday, March 14".

I've looked for plugins and tried the old code in Wordpress but no success.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
function getNextFriday() {
    var today = new Date();
    var nextFriday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-today.getDay()+7+5);
  // TODO: change to the apropriate time
    return nextFriday;
}

window.setTimeout(changeMyDate, getNextFriday()-new Date());

function changeMyDate() {
  console.log('Time to change the date');
  window.setTimeout(changeMyDate, getNextFriday() - new Date());
}
```

Comment: Your *getNextFriday()* does what its name is about. Can you specify the problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to work in Wordpress.  It was originally in HTML.  The developer that built it is no longer with us so I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get it to work with the new site.

Comment: You might want to be a more specific about what's going wrong and what you want. The function is working properly as it is. Also you might want to show what you have tried already.

Comment: Ok. The function *getNextFriday()* will return you a timestamp of the upcomming friday. This will be executed, as soon as this scipt was loaded in the browser of your visitor. The timeout will be set to get a new friday in return, but currently does not assign this to any element. Do you really want to use this timeout? *issue a:* most of the time, the next friday is a lot of days in future. the user will reload/click a link etc in between. *issue b:* if you want me to do some action in this time, I don't care, if it updates friday night to next friday with same offer.

Comment: What I have tried is pasting the text into a Wordpress post as I do other scripts.  But it shows the text and does not recognize this as a script.  Maybe I left out a tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can use the function `strtotime` to turn a word into a date, like this:

```
<?php

$date_friday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Friday'));
print $date_friday;
```

Since today is the 3rd of March, it will print March 7, all the way until Saturday, at which point it will flip to the 14th.

I'm not sure if there is a true Javascript equivalent of PHP's `strtotime`, but the `Date.parse` function does not quite seem to cut it.

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK -> NaN
var date = Date.parse("Friday");
```

I found a couple of different `strtotime` type functions written in Javascript that supposedly mimic PHP's version, but this one here returns false or a negative timestamp:

[PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime/)

```
// RETURNS NEGATIVE TIMESTAMP -> -1976781854 
document.write(strtotime('next Friday', Date.now()));

// RETURNS FALSE
document.write(strtotime('Friday', Date.now()));
```

This one I couldn't get to work for some reason:

[datetime.js](https://gist.github.com/josefig/1630428)

So, I guess what I am suggesting is that if it's at all possible to generate the timestamp from within PHP and then pass that to your Javascript, that would make things really straightforward.  Otherwise, one thing you can try is to try and find a working `strtotime` equivalent for Javascript.

Here is an example of how to insert a PHP date into a Javascript variable.

```
// JAVASCRIPT
var date_next_friday = '<?php print date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Friday')); ?>';
console.log(date_next_friday);
```

Comment: Got it to work.  Had to install a Wordpress plugin called 'Insert PHP' to get the post to read the PHP as code and not text.  Thanks!